# How to disable scrolling in ListView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms ListView has some tendency to stop stretching after some maximal height. When I put too many items in ListView, it creates scrollbar and height of it doesn't increase while I'm adding more of them.

It could be confusing to user if `<ListView>` with scrollbar is inside `<ScrollView>` object that has scrollbar too. Layout bahaves unnaturally, forcing user to scroll to the end of listview to be able to continue scrolling scrollView.

So, summing up:

**How can I disable scrollbar in ListView, forcing it to have the height of all its interior children?**

Children don't have equal heights. Also, they can change during app lifetime.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- some buttons and labels -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="20">
                            <!-- Some information -->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Platform on which I test my app: Windows 10 UWP.

Comment: Are you using ScrollView with ListView inside of it?

Comment: @jzeferino yes, I am

Comment: Isn't recommended to do that. Normally if you want that you should use footer and header of the listview.

Comment: Are there any other ways to use data binding from c# List<>? It's not necessary for me to use ListView. I just need to loop for each object in List and view its data.

Comment: And I need to do this in XAML. No foreach loops in C# code to make UI.

Comment: The best way is to use List.

Comment: Can you explain why are you using a Scrollview? What's the issue in solely using a ListView?

Comment: I'm using scroll view, because I want to also display some Entries and buttons above listview

Comment: if you want to display a list of items use a RepeaterView like this one https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21635/xforms-needs-an-itemscontrol/p2

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis thanks, looks much better now. And didn't require any big changes in my XAML

Answer (score 13):

I also face the same problem,I solved it by using Bindable
StackLayout inside Scroll View.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can the BindableLayout be bound with a any list of any type of object like the ListView?

Comment: Yes you can bind any type of object

Answer (score 8):

`Listview` already has an inbuilt scroll mechanism, you should never try to put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`.

`ListView` uses UI Virtualization, which means, it will only create required items in the visible view, and not all the items. For example, if you load 240 countries, it will only actually create 20 countries and as you scroll, it will create more or reuse existing items.

By putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, you will disable UI virtualization.

Infact, `Xamarin.Forms` does not do anything special for scrolling, it is feature of underlying platform Android/iOS/Windows that provide UI virtualization to improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, wherein I have a CollectionView which lists a bunch of records. Each record may have one or more child elements that I need to display without scrolling.

I solved it by setting the inner ListView scroll property and adding a box view on top of it so users cannot scroll the list.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!-- inner list view -->
  <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" SelectionMode="None">
   <!-- content here -->
  </ListView>
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```